# How to add Authorization Header to Angular http request?

Tags: angular, go, gorilla

This is my first post.

I've just started learning Go and Angular and I'm attempting to connect the angular app to a go api.  I've written both and am stuck identifying the root of the problem. I thought it was a CORS problem, but it works fine if I don't include the headers line of code in my Angular http request. At this point I'm just trying to add the header. The authorization code isn't implemented yet.

Both apps are running locally with the Go app on port 5000 and Angular on 4200

Angular http request that doesn't work:

```
this.http.get<ProjectedBalance>(requestUrl, {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')})
    .subscribe(data => {
     this.projBalance = data.projBalance;
   }
```

Angular http request that works:

```
this.http.get<ProjectedBalance>(requestUrl)
    .subscribe(data => {
     this.projBalance = data.projBalance;
   }
```

I'm getting this error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403

I'm using the gorilla/mux and gorilla/handlers in my go code

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.HandleFunc("/home/{endDate}", GetProjBalance).Methods("GET", "OPTIONS")
headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization"})
originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"})
//start server on port
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":5000", handlers.CORS(originsOk, headersOk, methodsOk)(router)))
```

Headers from Chrome Dev Tools

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/home/2020-12-21
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:[::1]:5000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
view source
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 20 Nov 2017 21:39:43 GMT

Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9,uz;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:5000
Origin:http://localhost:4200
```

Comment: Consider rephrasing your post in the form of a question...

Comment: I'm not sure why `handlers.CORS` isn't working but if you DON'T use CORS, you'll need to proxy your development requests to port 5000. In production you'll be running on port 80 so there's no conflict, but since you're using angular's dev server and running your go server locally, `localhost:4200` and `localhost:5000` are different origins. I'm not sure what the "angular 5 way" to do this is but `webpack-dev-server` has an ultra simple `proxy` field in the `package.json` and you basically want to replicate that.

Comment: Hello gobuckeyes could you please provide me with the list of headers your client sends in it's request to the API _(from the network tab in dev-tools)_. Also does the issue remain if you set all 3 **CORS** to `{"*"}`?

Comment: @Mihailo  I posted the headers from the dev-tools. Changing all three CORS to {"*"} changed the error to a 405 - Method not allowed. Thank you

Comment: Try turning the `AllowedMethods()` back to what they were. There should be 2 requests sent from your client one has the method `OPTIONS` and the other should be `GET` (for this particular) request. After you revert `AllowedMethods` try sending the request again, and if the error persists update the question with the data from the `GET` request.

Comment: @Mihailo The headers listed above are what's returned with the AllowedMethods() set as shown in the post right above them.  I think I posted both the Options Request and the Get Request. I don't think I see any others in the dev tools.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Regarding the best way of handling Authentication headers in **Angular > 4** it's best to use
`Http Interceptors` for adding them to each request, and afterwards using
`Guards` for protecting your routes.

Here's a full example of an `AuthInterceptor` that I'm using in my app:

> auth.interceptor.ts

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Accept'       : 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${AuthService.getToken()}`,
      },
    });

    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

You'll need to register your interceptor in the `app.module` as a provider:

> app.module.ts

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthInterceptor } from '../auth/auth.interceptor';

...

imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
],
providers: [
    {
      provide : HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi   : true,
    },
    ...
],

...
```

You can read about this method further in this [post](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8).

---

Regarding the **Go**'s side of things, this is most likely a case of mismatch between
**Request Headers** you're sending and the headers **CORS** allow.
First thing you should try is allowing all of them:

```
headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"*"})
originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"})
```

And if the problem goes away try carefully structuring your **CORS** one by one to what your client is sending.

Comment: This worked for adding the header within the Angular app. Thanks! For the Go piece I was able to use this approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452804/angularjs-http-get-request-failed-with-custom-header-alllowed-in-cors/22457910#22457910

Comment: Neat! Glad I could be of some help :) Good luck!

Answer (score 33):

In case you don't want to add interceptor, this worked for me:

```
var header = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Authorization',  `Basic ${btoa(AuthService.getToken())}`)
}

this.http.get(url, header)
```

For Bearer,

```
set('Authorization',  `Bearer ${AuthService.getToken()}`)
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular 6 ==> HTTP Get request example with Authorization Header

```
public IsClientCreditCardExits(companyId: string, token: any) {
    let header = new Headers({ 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` });
    const options = new RequestOptions({
       headers: header,
    });
    return this._http.get(this.ApiURL + "api/Subscriptions/IsClientCreditCardExits/" + companyId + "/", options);    
}
```

Comment: RequestOptions is depricated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
this.http
        .get(url, return new RequestOptions({
          headers: new Headers({
            Authorization: `Bearer ${authtoken}`
          }),
        }))
        .map(res => res.json());
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example would fit a situation where you only want some headers added only when accessing resources that require authorization see code below. Kindly note that you need create the getToken method in your **authentication.service.ts**.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const accessToken: string = this.authenticationService.getToken();
    // set global application headers.
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'X-AppName': environment.xAppName,
        'X-Locale': 'en'
      }
    });
    // Set headers for requests that require authorization.
    if (accessToken) {
      const authenticatedRequest = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set(
          'Authorization',
          `Token token=${accessToken}`
        )
      });
      // Request with authorization headers
      return next.handle(authenticatedRequest);
    } else {
      // Request without authorization header
      return next.handle(request);
    }
  }
}
```

Register the interceptor in **app.module.ts** as show below:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthenticationInterceptorService } from './services/authentication-interceptor.service';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthenticationInterceptorService,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```