# how to solve 401 unauthorized with http.post method with correct token

Tags: angular, http, post, http-status-code-401

I'm creating a function with http.post however, everytime i execute it i always get the 401 error. im including the token from the service and placing it under the headers

```
deleteOrder(orderCode: string) {
    let deleteOrder = this.occEndpointsService.buildUrl(`/orders/${orderCode}/delete`);
    return this.clientTokenService.getClientToken().pipe(
      switchMap((token) => {
        return this.http
        .post(deleteOrder, {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token.access_token}`
          },
          withCredentials: true,
        })
        .pipe(
          map((result: any) => result),
          catchError((error: any) => throwError(error))
        );
      })
    )
  }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

im pretty sure im getting the same correct token cause when i test it in postman it works fine.

Comment: As a side note, Angular has middleware functionality, so you don't have to add the token manually foreach request you send.

Comment: Maybe this question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400929/how-to-add-authorization-header-to-angular-http-request

Answer (score 0):

Might be that you are missing content type. Try adding followings:

```
     headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token.access_token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept', 'application/json'
      },
```

It can also be that it is prevented by CORS.

Comment: i tried adding those items in the headers still getting the same 401 issue. there's no CORS error on the console as per checking