# Getting a simple server to display a web page

Tags: go, server

I'm writing a simple server as a project to help me learn Go. Here's its minimal form:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func serve(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    text := "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" + 
    "Host: localhost:1234\r\n" + 
    "Connection: close\r\n" + 
    "\r\n" + 
    "<!doctype html>\r\n" + 
    "<html>...</html>\r\n"

    // Greet the user, ignoring their request.
    io.WriteString(w, text)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", serve)
    http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil)
}
```

It works as expected in terms that it sends the desired text when a client connects to `localhost:1234`. But for some reason my browser displays the output as text instead of HTML, as desired. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830095/setting-http-headers-in-golang

Comment: Keep in mind that HTTP and HTML aren't implicitly tied together. Go will try and inspect the MIME type of your content and set the Content-Type header appropriately, but in some cases it cannot do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the proper `Content-Type` header in the `ResponseWriter` before you write the response. You don't need to send the HTTP header, as that's sent implicitly on the first call to `Write`, or explicitly via `WriterHeader`.

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
```

Comment: Oh I see -- Go is sending HTTP on its own, and my HTTP was passed after the actual HTTP. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you will open your page in any alternative of chrome inspector, you will see that it has:

`Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Which tells your browser how to interpret it. You can send additional header specifying the content type: `w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")` or just remove all you `GET ...` leaving just:

```
text := "<h1>page</h1><span>page2</span>"
```